# mysql full text wildcard search like regex

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-indexing

Upto now I have been using

```
WHERE col REGEXP 'IN (.*) WE TRUST'
```

But ever since adding the full index search to this column then this query is very slow.

I'm waning to know know how I could implement a wildcard search using full text index searches.

These are two queries that I have been playing with but still Im getting  lots of results that is unexpected and not sure at all why my query is pulling those results.

```
WHERE MATCH (markIdentification) AGAINST ('IN (.*) WE TRUST')
WHERE MATCH (markIdentification) AGAINST ('+IN (.*) +WE +TRUST')
WHERE MATCH (markIdentification) AGAINST ('+IN * +WE +TRUST')
```

These are the only ones that seem to get even close. 
Any suggestions?

Thank you

Update for question ref:

```
SELECT * from table
 WHERE MATCH (col) AGAINST ('+IN * +WE +TRUST')
   AND col LIKE '%IN (.*) WE TRUST%'
```

Is this correct? 
If not then how would you do it?

Comment: Use `MATCH()` to get a list of candidates and then `LIKE` to whittle them down.

Comment: when you say a list of candidates. you mean to use the match as I am above then then another add on query clause. Ill update the question to confirm. Thanks for your speedy response

Comment: I mean, use `MATCH()` in a subquery.  Then use `LIKE` in the outer query.

Comment: Thank you both. These are really helpful answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FULLTEXT search engine ignores words shorter than three characters. You can [set the `innodb_ft_min_token_size` option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size) to change that, then regenerate your FULLTEXT indexes.

The + (and -) syntax in AGAINST are [boolean search mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) things. So to use + you need

```
WHERE MATCH (markIdentification) AGAINST ('+IN +WE +TRUST' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
```

BOOLEAN mode has lots of special characters to control searches, but `*` standing alone is not one of them. You can say `'TRUST*'` to match `trust`, `trustee`, and `trusted`.

Taking Gordon's suggestion, you might try this:

```
WHERE MATCH (markIdentification) AGAINST ('+IN +WE +TRUST' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
  AND  markIdentification REGEXP 'IN (.*) WE TRUST'
```

This will use your FULLTEXT index to look for possible matches, and REGEXP to get more exact results. The expensive REGEXP operation, then, can run on many fewer rows.

(Beware `IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE` when your tables don't have many rows. It can give strange results. The indexer decides which words are too common to bother with, and if you have a small number of words, that decision gets distorted.)

Comment: . . Without a subquery, do you know that the `match()` is executed first?

Comment: No, @GordonLinoff, I don't know for sure. Worth testing.

Comment: how to do a wildcard search using * to act like "like %trust%"
I tried *trust* but its not working, the only case it works is "trust*", so it returns results starts with "trust" 
 but how to get results contains the word "trust" regardless if it i in the end or the beginning?

Comment: @MoauyaMeghari You'd be wise to ask another question. I don't understand what you want.

Comment: I search for "trust" word, I want to return results contains the word "trust" not only results started with "trust"